# Change and update geometry mesh at runtime

Tags: qt, qt3d

This [question and answer](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-October/019187.html), in Oct 2015, implies it is possible to change `Qt3D` mesh and update it:

#### Question

> I want to use Qt3d in a situation that involves dynamic runtime 
>   changes of geometric data on the application side.
>
> What is the best way to dynamically change a mesh for an entity?
>
> I'd rather do all this on the C++ side, but QMesh doesn't seem to 
>   provide an API for changing the mesh data.
>
> I looked at some other examples of making a custom QAbstractMesh class 
>   and QAbstractMeshFunctor. It looks like I could possibly make a custom 
>   mesh type to do what I need but I have a question. If I keep a 
>   reference to the QMeshDataPtr that I make from the functor, can I 
>   simply modify the mesh data whenever I want and the entities that 
>   reference it will update automatically?

#### Answer

> The API for this has changed a little in 5.6. The geometric data is
>   now  contained in one or more QBuffer objects and is referenced by one
>   or  more QAttributes that describe the data layout in the buffers. The
>   QAttributes are rendered by adding them to a QGeometryRenderer
>   component.
>
> You can either update the above objects on the main thread and **call 
>   update()** or as before you can also use a functor to have the backend 
>   generate the dynamic data.

Now, my question is about calling `update()`. Exactly what section of `Qt3D` API is referred to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a test available at Qt installation directory on my Linux machine:

```sh
/home/{user}/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/Src/qt3d/tests/manual/custom-mesh-update-data-cpp/
```

which I discovered by following [this link](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/tests/manual/custom-mesh-update-data-cpp/main.cpp.html) when searching Google for `qt3d mesh update` keywords.

---

The above test is using [Qt3DRender::QBuffer API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qbuffer.html#updateData) to update mesh data:

> void QBuffer::updateData(int offset, const QByteArray &bytes)
>
> Updates the data by replacing it with bytes at offset.
>
> Note: This function can be invoked via the meta-object system and from QML. See Q_INVOKABLE.

Code looks like this:

```cpp
Qt3DRender::QBuffer *vertexDataBuffer;

// ...

QByteArray updateData;

// ...

vertexDataBuffer->updateData(pos,updateData);

// ...
```

Comment: I have this problem and I can't understand how should work with Buffer. how you estimate the value needed for buffer? It is difficult for me to understand its logic .

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Did you take a look at the provided test link?

Comment: if we have a geometry that has dynamic QVector3D vertexes . for example, a LineStrip that gets its vertexes from mouse, how should update this geometry?

Comment: @Parisa.H.R You might want to update by [API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qbuffer.html#updateData) whenever the QVector3D changes. Maybe by a signal-slot connection.